# Free opensource backup solution to keep 2 drives in sync

Tags: windows-backup, sync

I am trying to backup two portable harddrives. One being with me and the other being at a safe location. Every once I a while I want to connect both to my pc and have the one that was at another location to sync so they are both on the same version. I just want to copy the diff and it has to run in Windows Vista.

It is actually for my dad so the easier to use the better. It can be a bit more complicated if I have to set it up once :)

Comment: Not an answer as it doesn't meet your question exactly, but if you dropped the open source requirement, Microsoft Synctoy is free and very good. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52

Comment: Not answering your question, but if it's for your dad then I would not "backup" by keeping two drives in sync. If he deletes files from one, then they are removed from the other as soon as it's synced... (Any other backup solution for Windows is probably a duplicate question though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [rsync for windows](http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html), especially considering your already used to rsync.

Answer (score 1):

[Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) is a two-way file synchroniser. It is well integrated under Windows, and it has a GUI.

If you're always going to copy in the same direction, then Unison might be more complex than necessary. On the other hand, if you're sometimes going to synchronize in one direction and sometimes in the other direction, or if the direction of synchronization can't be automated (e.g. because you're synchronizing between two drives and you can't completely rely on a permanent identifier such as the drive letter), then Unison is the tool of choice.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using SyncBack and its quite good and it has free version also. You can find it from [2BrightSparks's website](http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/compare.html).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you connect to the remote hard drive, the answer is different.  If you can connect to it via a UNC (like you have a VPN between you and the remote machine), I would use Robocopy with the /mir switch. (Plus it is built in to Vista)

If you don't have a direct connect, I would look at some third party app like [dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) or [live sync](https://sync.live.com/home.aspx), [Pogoplug](http://www.pogoplug.com/home-en.html?) and have it sync.

I also like the all the already mentioned software, and the comment a sync isn't a backup (unless you are syncing the backup).

There are many correct answers, hard to say which is the best.